# how to fix page numbering in gridviev?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I can't find the way to fix page numbering in gridviev that they didn't change position depending on the contents of the gridview.

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tableResults" runat="server" DataSourceID="sourcePoints"
 CssClass = "table table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="tableResults_Bound"
 OnRowDataBound = "tableResults_DataBound" DataKeyNames="i_id" PageSize="4" AllowPaging="true"
 AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnRowDeleted="tableResults_RowDeleted" Height="300px" Width="100%"
 AutoGenerateEditButton = "True" OnRowUpdating="tableResults_RowUpdating"
 AllowSorting="true" OnRowUpdated="tableResults_RowUpdated" BorderStyle="None">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** There are few tricks while using page numbering in asp.net `GridView` control.

For Paging to work, your datasource must support it. If it does not, like a DataTable, then you have to do this yourself.

This code below might help you:

```
OnPageIndexChanging="myGridview_PageIndexChanging"

protected void myGridview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    DataView dv = gv.DataSource as DataView;
    DataTable dataTable = dv.Table;

    gv.DataSource = myDataTable;
    gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

**References** to look:

Here you are some ** complementary posts** that explains them step-by-step:

- [Some Tips and Tricks while Using ASP.NET GridView Paging](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=244)
- [Paging GridView with ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12962/Paging-GridView-with-ROW_NUMBER)

Answer (score 1):

Use  `PagerStyle`.

```
 <PagerStyle cssClass="YourPagerCss" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

And define your `css` .

For details see a link.
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Aug/18/GridView-and-Paging-Alignment